# Radius of convergence of power series of log z about a point

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I would like to determine the radius of convergence of the power series of log z expanded at -4+3i. I'm not sure how to tackle this - I've tried calculating the power series but I don't see what test or theorem I should use after that to find the radius of convergence. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac {d}{dz} \ln z = \frac 1z = \frac 1{a+ (z-a)} = \frac 1a \sum (\frac {(a-z)}{a})^n\\  
\ln z = \int \frac 1a \sum (\frac {(a-z)}{a})^n dz = \sum \frac 1n(\frac {(a-z)}{a})^n+\ln a$

radius of convergence:

Ratio test or root test will both give you the same thing.

$|\frac {a-z}{a}| < 1\\
|a-z| < |a|$

Answer (score 3):

There is a branch of $\log z$ holomorphic in $D(a,|a|)$, but not in $D(a,r)$ for any $r>|a|$. So basic complex analysis says the radius of convergence is $|a|$.

Comment: (using an appropriate branch of the logarithm, not the principal branch in this case)

Comment: Indeed, @RobertIsrael, this question is one I pose on a regular basis on the Complex Analysis prelim at my uni, exactly because (since it is posed on a regular basis...) the kids get jostled out of their belief that "log" somehow "knows" that we have "slit" the plane along the negative real axis, etc. My next quixotic quest is to get novices to say "_section_ over $U$" rather than "branch"... despite the tradition of the latter. :)

Comment: ... and, indeed, on the first few episodes of asking such a question, about $3/4$ of the people thought the radius of convergence was the distance to ... wait for it ... The Slit Along the Negative Real Axis. But, over the last 10 years, "the word has spread". Still, quasi-amazingly, some die-hards come and argue with me (about the grading of their prelim exam about this...) that "log" has a "jump" across the negative real axis, so it couldn't possibly be holomorphic on that larger disk. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett "Branch" v "section": I like to just refer to "a logarithm" in $U$.